# iOS notification for Qt Application

Tags: ios, qt, notifications

I am working on Qt which is cross platform. My requirement is iOS mobile notification.Found this sample for notification - https://github.com/siddeshpillai/qt-notification-cross-platform

Able to compile with iOS setup but not getting any notification message in Notification area.Can anyone please help me out regarding this concern.
Tested with iOS 10.3.3/11.2.2.

Please suggest me any other procedure to follow.
Note - Please dont suggest me anything related to V-Play plugin.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: How do you put iOS app in **background**? may be you need to procide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MohammadKanan The above attached github link ,I am able to show notification for Mac platform.So.I am expecting it should work for iOS

Comment: There is a note there saying _Notifications for iOS are triggered when the app is running in background_ ??